# Black screen at startup

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop

When I switch on my laptop (which was initially shut down), I am getting black screen for 30 seconds after which windows 7 logo appears and after that login is requested.

What should I do to correct this black screen problem?

Laptop specificatoin
i3-370 M processor
2.40GHz
Windows 7 home premium

Thanks

Comment: How long has it been like that? What have you done with the computer recently? Have you installed any new software or updates?

Comment: capture a boot trace with xbootmgr and upload the zipped trace so that I can see what is going on: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140247

Comment: @gronostaj I thought exactly like you and even reinstalled the OS but the problem is still persisting.
P.S: I have installed only those softwares which I have been using from long time but recently I have kept my computer to more hibernation. And also I ran MATLAB simulations in accelerator mode in a 2 month period. After this only the black screen problem has started.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I can't install the SDK since I am using internet from college proxy. Could u provide other ways?

Comment: download the ISO from a second PC, mount the ISO and run the setup: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have installed SDK successfully and ran that command in the url u gave. Windows unexpectedly shutdown and started startup repair. In that I opted for restore of windows when startup is fine. It ran for 15 minutes saying attempting repairs and restarted the windows. I didn't find SDK on computer, it might have been uninstalled in the process of repair.
Will this work like this only? Is problem solved? If not, tell me what to do.

Comment: install the SDK again. You get a BSOD caused by the DRIVERS flag. I also posted this on msfn. Run the command with the DRIVERS flag.